# Show overlay div on Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, webview

I am trying to show an overlay div as a progress indicator in an Android WebView. Js side of the equation is

```
$('.show_loading').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#loading').css("display", "block"); // same with .show
 });
```

This works on iOS, and Android Chrome browser when a link is tapped, but not within an WebView (including Android's default browser). It displays the div if I cancel the event (by returning false in the upper call), so I am wondering what's wrong with this approach?